# ANTLRv3: C target error handling. Changing System.err out

Tags: c, antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

Using ANTLRv3 I can build my parser which by default prints an error string to System.err typically on a console.

However, I have a different output to print errors out to, for example to a file (for logging), i.e. I am not working on a console. I was wondering what I have to do to print the error string in this case? I guess I would just have to change the definition of the function which is responsible for printing the error string but I can't locate it.

From this documentation https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687258/Error+reporting+and+recovery I can find that I simply need to override `emitErrorMessage()` but I can't locate it in my C target so I'm a bit confused how that would work.

I am working on ANTLR 3.5.2 C target. Using ANTLRv4 is not an option.

Unfortunately, I cannot find much reference projects which use C so I can't learn from them.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: OT: ANTLRv3: C target generates parsers, which evaluates conditions in opposite order than other targets. As result C target might be like 100x slower than Java/C++/other targets.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. unfortunately I don't have much of a choice

Comment: ahh I found It. C++ was created as a copy of C target. For C++ target I created these fixes (never got to mainstream). https://github.com/ibre5041/antlr3/commit/e36baba6c96a9ffa034cd6f61321c17d01abf7fc https://github.com/ibre5041/antlr3/commit/f4dd86759394ec32f9de9a73d3b7bd43931d9ab3 This changes condition evaluation order to be the same as in Java target. So instead of "if (sync_pred(X) && c == 'A')" it generates "if (c == 'A' && sync_pred(X))"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot override a C function (since it isn't virtual in the C target), but you can replace the error handler with your own to get the errors forwarded instead. See how I did it in the [old MySQL Workbench parser code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/6.3/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLSimpleParser.g#L63).

```
@parser::postinclude {
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { 
#endif

  // Custom error reporting function.
  void onMySQLParseError(struct ANTLR3_BASE_RECOGNIZER_struct *recognizer, pANTLR3_UINT8 *tokenNames); 

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
}

@parser::members {
}

@parser::apifuncs
{
 // Install custom error collector for the front end.
 RECOGNIZER->displayRecognitionError = onMySQLParseError;
}
```

The function `onMySQLParseError` is obviously what you have to change and implement in your C code.